# generate is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk

I am using `nltk` version 3.0.2
and when I use this code

```
import nltk 
from nltk.book import *

text3.generate()
```

I got error

```
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'generate'
```

and I have checked  that
the fourth note in the first chapter of the online NLTK book says that:

> The generate() method is not available in NLTK 3.0 but will be
>   reinstated in a subsequent version

I have tried with lower version of `nltk` 2.0 and also install both versions of `nltk` with different versions of Python then also it doesn't work so please help me that how can I use this `generate()` in Python `nltk`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/text.py) it looks like it has still not been added,it is also commented out from the demo function

```
#print("Automatically generated text:")
#text.generate()
#print()
```